# Borrow checker issue in `zip`-like function with a callback

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to implement a function that steps though two iterators at the same time, calling a function for each pair. This callback can control which of the iterators is advanced in each step by returning a `(bool, bool)` tuple. Since the iterators take a reference to a buffer in my use case, they can't implement the `Iterator` trait from the stdlib, but instead are used though a `next_ref` function, which is identical to `Iterator::next`, but takes an additional lifetime parameter.

```
// An iterator-like type, that returns references to itself
// in next_ref
struct RefIter {
    value: u64
}

impl RefIter {
    fn next_ref<'a>(&'a mut self) -> Option<&'a u64> {
        self.value += 1;
        Some(&self.value)
    }
}

// Iterate over two RefIter simultaneously and call a callback
// for each pair. The callback returns a tuple of bools
// that indicate which iterators should be advanced.
fn each_zipped<F>(mut iter1: RefIter, mut iter2: RefIter, callback: F)
    where F: Fn(&Option<&u64>, &Option<&u64>) -> (bool, bool)
{
    let mut current1 = iter1.next_ref();
    let mut current2 = iter2.next_ref();
    loop {
        let advance_flags = callback(&current1, &current2);
        match advance_flags {
            (true, true) => {
                current1 = iter1.next_ref();
                current2 = iter2.next_ref();
            },
            (true, false) => {
                current1 = iter1.next_ref();
            },
            (false, true) => {
                current2 = iter1.next_ref();
            },
            (false, false) => {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut iter1 = RefIter { value: 3 };
    let mut iter2 = RefIter { value: 4 };
    each_zipped(iter1, iter2, |val1, val2| {
        let val1 = *val1.unwrap();
        let val2 = *val2.unwrap();
        println!("{}, {}", val1, val2);
        (val1 < 10, val2 < 10)
    });
}
```

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `iter1` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:28:28
   |
22 |     let mut current1 = iter1.next_ref();
   |                        ----- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
28 |                 current1 = iter1.next_ref();
   |                            ^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
42 | }
   | - first borrow ends here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `iter2` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:29:28
   |
23 |     let mut current2 = iter2.next_ref();
   |                        ----- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
29 |                 current2 = iter2.next_ref();
   |                            ^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
42 | }
   | - first borrow ends here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `iter1` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:32:28
   |
22 |     let mut current1 = iter1.next_ref();
   |                        ----- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
32 |                 current1 = iter1.next_ref();
   |                            ^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
42 | }
   | - first borrow ends here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `iter1` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:35:28
   |
22 |     let mut current1 = iter1.next_ref();
   |                        ----- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
35 |                 current2 = iter1.next_ref();
   |                            ^^^^^ second mutable borrow occurs here
...
42 | }
   | - first borrow ends here
```

I understand why it complains, but can't find a way around it. I'd appreciate any help on the subject.

Link to this snippet in the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4a506ba2c7d2320b8128c2f9e9f1ca32&version=stable).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Since the iterators take a reference to a buffer in my use case, they can't implement the `Iterator` trait from the stdlib, but instead are used though a `next_ref` function, which is identical to `Iterator::next`, but takes an additional lifetime parameter.

You are describing a *streaming iterator*. There is a crate for this, aptly called [streaming_iterator](https://crates.io/crates/streaming_iterator). The documentation describes your problem (emphasis mine):

> While the standard `Iterator` trait's functionality is based off of
>   the `next` method, `StreamingIterator`'s functionality is based off of
>   a pair of methods: `advance` and `get`. This essentially splits the
>   logic of `next` in half (in fact, `StreamingIterator`'s `next` method
>   does nothing but call `advance` followed by `get`).
>
> This is required because of Rust's lexical handling of borrows (more
>   specifically a lack of single entry, multiple exit borrows). **If
>   `StreamingIterator` was defined like `Iterator` with just a required
>   `next` method, operations like `filter` would be impossible to define.**

The crate does not currently have a `zip` function, and certainly not the variant you have described. However, it's easy enough to implement:

```
extern crate streaming_iterator;

use streaming_iterator::StreamingIterator;

fn each_zipped<A, B, F>(mut iter1: A, mut iter2: B, callback: F)
where
    A: StreamingIterator,
    B: StreamingIterator,
    F: for<'a> Fn(Option<&'a A::Item>, Option<&'a B::Item>) -> (bool, bool),
{
    iter1.advance();
    iter2.advance();

    loop {
        let advance_flags = callback(iter1.get(), iter2.get());
        match advance_flags {
            (true, true) => {
                iter1.advance();
                iter2.advance();
            }
            (true, false) => {
                iter1.advance();
            }
            (false, true) => {
                iter1.advance();
            }
            (false, false) => return,
        }
    }
}

struct RefIter {
    value: u64
}

impl StreamingIterator for RefIter {
    type Item = u64;

    fn advance(&mut self) {
        self.value += 1;
    }

    fn get(&self) -> Option<&Self::Item> {
        Some(&self.value)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let iter1 = RefIter { value: 3 };
    let iter2 = RefIter { value: 4 };
    each_zipped(iter1, iter2, |val1, val2| {
        let val1 = *val1.unwrap();
        let val2 = *val2.unwrap();
        println!("{}, {}", val1, val2);
        (val1 < 10, val2 < 10)
    });
}
```

Comment: Should the last `iter1.advance();` be `iter2.advance();`?

Comment: @Douglas it certainly seems like it, but I was just following OP's logic. Presumably they had a method to their madness.

Comment: There's no method to that particular madness, it is a copy and paste error I made when removing stuff from the actual code. The reason for that particular version of `zip` is that fastq records (information about a snippet of DNA) often come in pairs, that are split into two different files. But sometimes those files contain a couple of unpaired records, which would lead to an ordinary zip going out of sync. Splitting the iterator is a great idea by the way. I guess I was missing the keyword `streaming iterator`, which made googling quite hard. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with this code is that `RefIter` is being used in two ways, which are fundamentally at odds with one another:

- Callers of `next_ref` recieve a reference to the stored value, which is tied to the lifetime of `RefIter`
- `RefIter`'s value needs to be mutable, so that it can be incremented on each call

This perfectly describes mutable aliasing (you're trying to modify 'value' while a reference to it is being held) - something which Rust is explicitly designed to prevent.

In order to make `each_zipped` work, you'll need to modify `RefIter` to avoid handing out references to data that you wish to mutate.
I've implemented one possibility below using a combination of `RefCell` and `Rc`:

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

// An iterator-like type, that returns references to itself
// in next_ref
struct RefIter {
    value: RefCell<Rc<u64>>
}


impl RefIter {
    fn next_ref(&self) -> Option<Rc<u64>> {
        let new_val = Rc::new(**self.value.borrow() + 1);
        *self.value.borrow_mut() = new_val;
        Some(Rc::clone(&*self.value.borrow()))
    }
}


// Iterate over two RefIter simultaniously and call a callback
// for each pair. The callback returns a tuple of bools
// that indicate which iterators should be advanced.
fn each_zipped<F>(iter1: RefIter, iter2: RefIter, callback: F)
    where F: Fn(&Option<Rc<u64>>, &Option<Rc<u64>>) -> (bool, bool)
{
    let mut current1 = iter1.next_ref();
    let mut current2 = iter2.next_ref();
    loop {
        let advance_flags = callback(&current1, &current2);
        match advance_flags {
            (true, true) => {
                current1 = iter1.next_ref();
                current2 = iter2.next_ref();
            },
            (true, false) => {
                current1 = iter1.next_ref();
            },
            (false, true) => {
                current2 = iter1.next_ref();
            },
            (false, false) => {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let iter1 = RefIter { value: RefCell::new(Rc::new(3)) };
    let iter2 = RefIter { value: RefCell::new(Rc::new(4)) };
    each_zipped(iter1, iter2, |val1, val2| {
        // We can't use unwrap() directly, since we're only passed a reference to an Option
        let val1 = **val1.iter().next().unwrap();
        let val2 = **val2.iter().next().unwrap();
        println!("{}, {}", val1, val2);
        (val1 < 10, val2 < 10)
    });
}
```

This version of `RefIter` hands out `Rc`s to consumers, instead of references. This avoids the issue of mutable aliasing - updating `value` is done by placing
a new `Rc` into the outer `RefCell`. A side effect of this is that consumers are able to hold onto an 'old' reference to the buffer (through the returned `Rc`), even after `RefIter` has advanced.

Comment: I don't think you are right in assuming that the design of `RefIter` itself is flawed. We can easily iterate through the iterators one at a time: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b43d24bbd5649b62d0b9612cfa9bc01a. When using an `Rc` I could just as well use an ordinary iterator, but in my use case I'd like to return references to different slices of the same buffer (which also changes as new data is read).

Comment: The problem seems to be more related to non-lexical lifetimes. We take a mutable reference to `current1` in the beginning of `each_zipped`. We then use the value to call the callback. At this point we don't need the reference anymore. We *should* be free to call `next_ref` again, but the compiler doesn't seem to notice that.

Comment: I think you're right about non-lexical lifetimes - the lifetimes of `current1` and `current2` extend to the end of the function, even though they're not used after `callback`.